# Bump/Normal map leaving ridges?

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor, normal-map

Recently I’ve noticed something off with my bump/Normal maps. More specifically how they’re rendered out. I end up with these weird ridges as shown below. It was like this in Blender v2.79, so I know it’s not v2.8-specific. As far as I know I’m feeding textures through proper nodes. For Normal maps I’ll use a Normal map node; height maps go through a bump node.

I don’t believe it’s an issue with the maps themselves. I’ve run the same maps through Arnold’s shader system in Maya and haven’t seen the same issues.

Does anyone have any suggestions? How do you set up the shader nodes to use your bump/Normal maps? Am I missing a button or setting somewhere?

[image]

For further reference:
only reference I have of what I'm trying to make:
[image]

My progress so far:
[image]

The texture should be like that pattern swatch on the upper right.

I’ve managed to get it close, but I’m dealing with those same issues. I’ve isolated it in the first image above, to show what I’m referring to when I say “ridges.” This is something I have come across many times, and I assume I’m doing something wrong with my node setup.

Comment: have you marked seams and unwrapped your object?

Comment: Yes.. I unwrapped before texturing

Comment: there must be a problem with your unwrap, could you share your file?

Comment: How is this remotely related to unwrapping?

Comment: your unwrap will determine how your pattern will be displayed on the surface, so if it's not correct it can give strange things. Maybe it's something else, but what?

Comment: Yes... I do appreciate your suggestion. Forgive me if I don't sent you my file. I've unwrapped it and managed my seams. There's no stretching and enough pexel density for my purposes... I've come here hopefully to answer that question, but since you asked; I suspect it has to do with the way blender is handling the image I've put through for bump mapping. It's a 16 bit grayscale non-lossy image.

Comment: Why would it handle it differently on these faces?

Comment: is it the same thing on all the faces? I thought it only happened on the sides, sorry if I misunderstood... so perhaps share the pattern so we can test...

Comment: Also, have you converted your image to a displacement one, like with CrazyBump or this kind of software? A simple b&w picture is not optimal. And I've tried 8 bit or 16 bit and it doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Can you share your bump map? You say it's 16-bit but it could possibly be that Blender is only interpreting it as 8-bit and it's only covering a narrow range (this is an unfounded guess at this stage) - the banding looks possibly like it's due to low precision.

Comment: This issue got solved on [Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/bump-normal-map-leaving-ridges/1129524/22). Can we relay the information, close it, or leave it as it is?